# Falcon error: on_get, on_post... could not be called

Tags: python, falconframework

I am writing a website using Python and falcon. I found that recently, only init are called but the rest (`on_get`, `on_post`...) are not. Does anyone know some potential reasons?

I tried waitress, gunicorn... but all result in the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.